# How to manage routes in reactjs with dashboard and e-commerce page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I've been trying to manage the routes inside my App.js, I already created the dashboard and also its navbar and side navbar for my dashboard. So my problem is with the routes. I already tried playing with the routes to be able to access the page for my dashboard but I encounter a problem when the dashboard is working, my shop page will not work and shows nothing. Sorry I hope you'll understand my question.

```
import { Switch,Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

import ProtectedRoute from './routes/ProtectedRoute';

import Login from './components/shop/auth/Login';
import Register from './components/shop/auth/Register';
import Forgot from './components/shop/auth/Forgot';
import ChangePassword from './components/shop/auth/ChangePassword';
import ErrorPage from './components/shop/ErrorPage';
import Order from './components/shop/Order';
import Navbar from './components/shop/partials/Navbar';
import Footer from './components/shop/partials/Footer';
import Shop from './components/shop/Shop';
import ItemDetails from './components/shop/ItemDetails';
import Cart from './components/shop/Cart';
import Customize from './components/shop/Customize';
import UserProfile from './components/shop/profile/UserProfile';
import UserOrders from './components/shop/profile/UserOrders';
import UserSideNav from './components/shop/profile/UserSideNav';
import UserHistory from './components/shop/profile/UserHistory';
import UserDelete from './components/shop/profile/UserDelete';
import About from './components/shop/About';
import Contact from './components/shop/Contact';
// admin
import Dashboard from './components/admin/Dashboard';
import LoginAdmin from './components/admin/auth/LoginAdmin';
import SidebarAdmin from './components/admin/partials/SidebarAdmin';
import NavbarAdmin from './components/admin/partials/NavbarAdmin';

const App = () => {

  const [user,setUser] = useState('');

  // profile page navigation function
  const [profileActive,setProfileActive] = useState('Details');
  const navigateProfile = (page) => {
    setProfileActive(page);
  }

  // set the logged in status of the user
  const [authStatus, setAuthStatus] = useState(true);

  // create a route in the backend to authenticate the users, then pass a json
  useEffect(() => {
    const abortController = new AbortController();
    Axios.get('/api/auth', { signal: abortController.signal })
    .then((res) => {
      if(res.data.isAuth) {
        setAuthStatus(res.data.isAuth);
      }
      if(!res.data.isAuth) {
        setAuthStatus(res.data.isAuth);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
    return () => abortController.abort();
  });
  
  // saves the state of the logged in user even on refresh
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem("user");
    setUser(JSON.parse(data));
  },[])
  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
  })
  return (
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/login'>
            <Login setUser={setUser} setAuthStatus={setAuthStatus} authStatus={authStatus}/>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path='/register'>
            <Register authStatus={authStatus} />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path='/forgot'>
            <Forgot />
            <Footer />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path='/changepassword/:token/:id'>
            <ChangePassword />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/notfound">
            <ErrorPage />
          </Route>
        
            <> { /* shop routes */}
              <Navbar user={user} setAuthStatus={setAuthStatus} />
              <Switch>
                <ProtectedRoute exact path='/' component={Shop} isAuth={authStatus}  />
                <Route exact path='/order'>
                  <Order />
                  <Footer />
                </Route>
                <Route exact path='/item/details'>
                  <ItemDetails />
                  <Footer />
                </Route>
                <Route exact path='/cart'> 
                  <Cart />
                  <Footer />
                </Route>
                <Route exact path='/customize'>
                  <Customize />
                  <Footer />
                </Route>
                <Route exact path='/profile/:userName'>
                  <div className="flex justify-center relative m-8">
                    <div className="flex max-w-7xl w-full">
                        <UserSideNav navigateProfile={navigateProfile} />
                        <>
                          { profileActive === 'Details' && <ProtectedRoute exact path='/profile/:userName' component={UserProfile} isAuth={authStatus} /> }
                          { profileActive === 'Orders' && <ProtectedRoute exact path='/profile/:userName' component={UserOrders} isAuth={authStatus} /> }
                          { profileActive === 'History' && <ProtectedRoute exact path='/profile/:userName' component={UserHistory} isAuth={authStatus} /> }
                          { profileActive === 'DeleteAccount' && <ProtectedRoute exact path='/profile/:userName' component={UserDelete} isAuth={authStatus} /> }
                        </>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </Route>
    
                <Route exact path='/about'>
                  <About />
                  <Footer />
                </Route>

                <Route exact path='/contact-us'>
                  <Contact />
                  <Footer />  
                </Route>

                <Redirect to='/notfound' />
              </Switch>
              
            </>
        </Switch>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why can't you create a Route for your Dashboard component like you have with all of your other components?

Comment: Sorry, your question is a bit unclear, it sounds like you are asking how to make a React component, but I don't think this is what you are wanting to know or get an answer to. Can you clarify?

Comment: Hi Coot3, well I already tried it but when I add the dashboard components, the pages of the shop are not being rendered when I'm trying to access it.

Comment: I already edited it sir. I hope you can understand

Comment: You've imported `Dashboard`, add a route for it?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 'BrowserRouter' like this:

```
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import About from './components/shop/About';

<BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component={About}>
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```